# How to use イコール to compare things? How is it different from 同じ?

Tags: usage, synonyms

I've heard sometimes that イコール is used sometimes to imply that things are similar. What would be a correct expression to use イコール? Furthermore, how is it different from using 同じ to say that things are similar?

以上、どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

AとBは同じです means that A and B are similar.
They are two different things.

AイコールB means that A and B are a unique thing, with two names.

Comment: Call it a mathematician bias…

Comment: It's been my experience that イコール is used to mean "exactly, exactly the same thing to the point of substitution", often to deny that two things can be conflated as such. 同じ is much more general. This definitely happens because イコール is specifically a math term :)

Answer (score 2):

イコール is "equals", and 同じ【おなじ】 is "same".

The terms have exactly the same implications as they do in English. You could even say they are *equal* to their English counterparts. ;)