# How do you read simple arithmetic equations in Japanese?

Tags: readings, mathematics

My dictionary (EN → JP) suggests to translate "Three multiplied by four is twelve" as

> 3 × 4 = 12

without giving a hint as to how to read this in Japanese.

How do you read simple arithmetic equations (involving only +, –, × and ÷) like the one above in Japanese?

Comment: Related:  [How to say 24 divided by 8 equals 3](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6087/78) and [How to use イコール to compare things? How is it different from 同じ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2508/78).

Comment: It seems fitting that I add: fractions are read in reverse order to common U.S. English. 3/4, Three over four is read, 四分の三. 4 parts 3, or more appropriately translated "of 4 parts there are 3."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`+`: 足{た}す
`-`: 引{ひ}く
`/`: 割{わ}る
`*`: 掛{か}ける

And you just say the terms normally in order. So your example of `3 * 4 = 12` would be ３かける４は１２. Note that = becomes は, similar to how we use "is" in English. As @blutorange mentioned, you can use イコール to mean "equals," however in most situations you'll be good using は.

You learn these things quickly when listening to students recite their 九九{くく}.

For some bonus terminology, you can refer to exponents by using #乗{じょう}, so like ２の二乗は４ or ２の３乗は８. Similarly you can refer to roots with #乗根{じょうこん} (although as @jovanni points out it's normal to use 平方根{へいほうこん} for square roots).

Comment: The 九九 in Japanese is usually learnt with a [very different reading](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%9D%E4%B9%9D), though. E.g. 3*3=9 is さざんがく.

Comment: interesting. the kids i've heard have just been saying ~かける~は～

Comment: Especially in math (classes) and with equations such as x+3=7, the "=" sign is also read イコール("equal(s)").

Comment: 2乗根 is rarely used. use [平方]{へいほう}[根]{こん} instead.

Comment: @jovanni thank you! sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 9):

You can read the arithmetic operators as follows:

```
　　　+　　　たす　　　　（足す）
　　　-　　　ひく　　　　（引く）
　　　×　　　かける　　　（掛ける）
　　　÷　　　わる　　　　（割る）
```

In place of the equals sign, you'd most likely use a particle such as `は`, much as we might say "three times four ***is*** twelve" in English to make a complete sentence out of it.  Your example looks like this:

```
　　３　　　×　　　４　＝　１２
　　さん、かける、よんは、じゅうに
```

Comment: As an aside, if you want fancy math symbols like `×` and `÷` instead of `*` and `/`, you can type `かける` and `わる` to get them.  (On this computer, I can also get them by typing `すうがく`, which has lots of math symbols, and `きごう`, which has all sorts of symbols.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to offer one more alternative, that of using になります at the end of this sentence. This is more formal and less common than just leaving it out.

> 3 × 4 = 12
>
> さんかけるよんはじゅうにになります。

Comment: Please correct me if it is never said this way.

Comment: I think `となります` is also used.

Comment: I think である　and　なり should be listed as  well, but I am not 100% on their usage--just rephrasing a previous sawa answer.

Comment: So "san kakeru yon wa juuni daeru" would be considered okay, but not, say... "san kakeru yon wa juuni desu"...?

Comment: Curious, there is no numeral in native Japanese? Everybody seems to write Arabic numerals.