# Math in Japanese

Tags: readings, mathematics

I am currently reviewing all of my high school math classes, but doing it in Japanese instead, so I found some websites that are meant to help Japanese high school students in math. Through this method I have been able to learn some math-specific words but the reading for equations like y = x + 2 are not given. This equation is quite simple and a quick search on Google led to my answer, but what about something like this: *f*(x) = 3x<sup>2</sup> + 4x - 12, or derivatives and integrals.

I don't think that it is efficient to write down every equation I can't read in Japanese, so my question is:

Is there a general method I can use to read most equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *f*(x) = 3x<sup>2</sup> + 4x - 12 　　（ f(x) = 3x^2 + 4x - 12 ）

I think the following page can answer most of your questions.

http://izumi-math.jp/sanae/report/suusiki/suusiki.htm

```
y=f(x)    y イコール f x
          y イコール f かっこ x （かっこ） 

aⁿ  （a^n）      aのn乗 　[e.g.  2乗]
```

This page doesn't have 足す and 引く, but you prob. already know those. —
「　いち　足す　に　は、さん。」

**y = 3x<sup>2</sup>** 　（y=3x^2）　→ 　「　y　は、　さん　エックス　二乗　」

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12122015672
>
> x^2 + ( y - x^(2/3) )^2 = 1
>
> これなんて読みますか？
>
> エックスの二乗 プラス カッコ ワイ マイナス 三乗根 エックスの二乗 カッコ閉じて その二乗 イコール 一 かな？

I like the 2nd answer slightly better:

> x２乗 プラス かっこ y マイナス エックスの３分の２乗 かっこ閉じるの ２乗 イコール １

Related page from 3 years ago :
[How do you read simple arithmetic equations in Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12545/how-do-you-read-simple-arithmetic-equations-in-japanese)